# Can stock market gains be better protected under an LLC arrangement?

Tags: taxes, stocks, investing, limited-liability-company

As I understand it, if one has a business, profits can be reinvested to show zero net profits, so as to avoid tax. (I could be wrong about this, feel free to correct me.)

I'm wondering if one can do something similar for stock market profits.

Instead of investing in stocks as a person, invest in them under an LLC umbrella. Then, re-invest the subsequent profits to acquire some capital asset, thus reducing the taxable profits.

Sounds too easy... what do I have wrong?

Edit: Since lots of readers seem to be confused about this question: this is a general question (not country-specific) on tax-avoidance. Something that all corporations are expected to do.

Comment: Tax avoidance is illegal in most countries.

Comment: Avoidance is not only legal, but expected. Evasion is illegal. OP has the details all wrong. Although I enjoy exactly what he describes within my IRA and 401(k).

Comment: To answer your last question - you have it all wrong !!!

Comment: Relevant reading - http://www.capitalmanagementservicesgroup.com/startahedgefund/hedgefundtaxes.html

Comment: Tax questions require you specify the country.

Answer (score 2):

All corporate gains are taxed at the same rate as corporate income, for the corporate entity, so this actually can be WORSE than the individual capital gains tax rates.

There are a lot of things you can do with trading certain asset classes, like opening you up to like-kind re-investment tax perks, but I can't think of anything that helps with stocks.

Also, in the US there is now a law against doing things solely to avoid tax if they have no other economic purpose. So be conscious about that, you'll need to be able to rationalize at least a thin excuse for why you jumped through all the hoops.

Comment: An LLC with a sole owner becomes a pass thru entity anyway. Useful for a rental property to protect one's other assets, not so much for this purpose.

Comment: If I have a rental property, I can reinvest profits in buying, say, a lawn mower, and that gets counted as a business expenditure/expense.

If I have a general purpose LLC, I can take profits from one part of the LLC and reinvest them in another part of the LLC to count them as a business expense. My question was in regards to this very concept. Whether I could take profits from one part of the LLC (e.g. stock market profits), and reinvest them to say, buy a taxi (for the other part of the LLC which is a taxi business, say). And thereby reduce my taxes (due to lower profits).

Comment: @user1883050 that would not be an expense, that would be a capital asset

Answer (score 1):

The thing you get wrong is that you think the LLC doesn't pay taxes on gains when it sells assets.

It does.

In fact, in many countries LLC are considered separate entities for tax properties and you have double taxation - the LLC pays its own taxes, and then when you withdraw the money from the LLC to your own account (i.e.: take dividends) - you pay income tax on the withdrawal again. Corporate entities usually do not have preferential tax treatment for investments.

In the US, LLC is a pass-though entity (unless explicitly chosen to be taxed as a corporation, and then the above scenario happens). Pass-through entities (LLCs and partnerships) don't pay taxes, but instead report the gains to the owners, which then pay taxes as if the transaction was their personal one. So if you're in the US - investing under LLC would have no effect whatsoever on your taxes, or adverse effect if you chose to treat it as a corporation.

In any case, investing in stocks is not a deductible expense, and as such doesn't reduce profits.

Comment: OK, investing in stocks is not a deductible expense, but what if profits from stocks were reinvested in buying say, a taxi, for a taxi business under the same LLC?

Comment: @user1883050 so you'd have capital gains and schedule C losses. You don't need LLC for that.

Comment: LLC is double taxed only if you decide it to be taxed as a C Corporation. If you decide it to be taxed as S Corporation then you will avoid the double taxation.